# How can I start my Quarkus application without tests?

Tags: quarkus

I'm a Quarkus newbie and using Eclipse with the Quarkus plugin.

Whether I start manually with `mvnw clean quarkus:dev` or using an Eclipse Quarkus launch configuration, the application always seems to run tests.

I see something like

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 62021
Press [h] for more options>
Tests paused
Press [r] to resume testing, [h] for more options>
Press [r] to resume testing, [o] Toggle test output, [h] for more options>
```

and nothing happens for a while until then I see the Quarkus logo, my log messages etc.

Perhaps I haven't read the documentation thoroughly enough, but I found no configuration to switch this off and start the application straight in dev mode.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The output literally says that tests are paused, that is, not running. The application starts straight in dev mode -- you don't have to do anything. If you have to wait for too long before the Quarkus logo appears, there may be a problem, but it's most likely not related to continuous testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in the output is continuous testing. Works in conjunction with hot reload where tests run immediately after code changes have been saved.
More information you can find here: [Quarkus - Continuous Testing](https://quarkus.io/guides/continuous-testing)

Continuous testing can be disabled via configuration property `quarkus.test.continuous-testing=disabled`. The default mode of continuous testing is `paused`. See: [Quarkus - Continuous Testing - Configuration](https://quarkus.io/guides/continuous-testing#configuring-continuous-testing)

Comment: Thanks! I still see `Press [h] for more options>` though. Is that the minimal startup time I can get?

Comment: @eerriicc I think yes, because you're running your application in development mode.